# how to enable "Load data local infile " in mysql JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i am trying to load data into a table through Java program using JDBC.
i have already done these steps :

> sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Then add:

> [mysqld] local-infile = ON
>
> [mysql] local-infile = ON

on running the this program:

> Code:
>
> ```
> Statement statement = con.createStatement();String sql="Create table tbl_user_analysis (Country varchar(10),State Varchar(20))";
> statement.executeUpdate("drop table tbl_user_analysis");
> statement.executeUpdate(sql);
> statement.executeUpdate("load data local infile /home/Asus/workspace/example/xyz into table tbl_user_analysis fields terminated by '\\t' ");
> ```

But i am getting this exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '/home/Asus/workspace/example/xyz into table
>   tbl_user_analysi' at line 1   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
>     at example1.example.main(example.java:281)

Comment: did you restart mysqld?

Comment: @kostja yes i also did that but, i am getting the same exception

Comment: I got it its a Syntax Error (i forgot to use **'** single quote): load data local infile **'/home/Asus/workspace/example/xyz'** into table tbl_user_analysis fields terminated by '\\t' "